# How do I attach text to text in another cell?

Tags: mysql, concatenation

Hey working in MySql and creating a bank of names.

Right now I have a column titled "team name" ie "Ohno Romo". I want a column titled "opp code" to look like this: "team(Ohno Romo)"

If anyone can help me add the "team" and parenthesis before and after the team name that would be really helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Use the `CONCAT()` function to concatenate strings.

Comment: `CONCAT('team(', teamname, ')')`

Answer (score 0):

For this type of string manipulation, use `CONCAT()`

```
set @str_1 = 'opp code', @str_2 = 'Ohno Romo';

select concat(@str_1, '(', @str_2, ')');
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html

Comment: trying to run a code similar to this in mysql that isn't working.                         UPDATE twentytenusers
SET oppcode
SELECT concat('Team', '(', team, ')');